# How do I replace a busted garage door hinge #0?

Tags: garage-door

My home's garage door has several #0 hinges in the interior (see picture below). Ten years ago or so I noticed a few of them were broken, so I bought replacements online and installed them without issue.

Tonight I noticed another hinge was broken so I jumped online to order a replacement, but it appears now that #0 hinges are no longer sold? The websites I found state that garage door hinges start at #1. I did find a seller on eBay selling #0 hinges, but he's asking *$95 per hinge*!

I presume #0 hinges have been phased out. Can I use a #1 hinge, instead, and just replace the broken one? Or do I need to replace all #0 hinges with #1 hinges? Or can I not use #1 hinges as replacements at all?

Thanks

[image: Garage door hinge #0.]

Answer (score 0):

The number of the hinge simply specifies "how tall they are" - i.e. the distance between the plane of the door and the hinge shaft.   That decides the distance between the (actually slightly slanted) garage door track, and the outer seal of the door.

Using too tall a hinge will cause the door to jam against the frame/seal.  It won't drop all the way, will bind badly, and after you adjust the garage door track to stop the binding, it will leak air badly.

Comment: Therefore, in order to use a #1 where a #0 used to go, either the hinge pivot point needs to be modified or the track's distance from the wall needs to be adjusted to make the whole thing fit. Correct?

Comment: @FreeMan modifying the hinge pivot point is what the size change does. Yes, you would need to change the track's distance from the wall if you didn't want it to bind at the bottom.